# How to return to UIKit viewController from SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation, uikit, viewcontroller

I am using xib views and SwiftUI views in same app. Now I have situation when I open SwiftUI view from UIKit viewController and I want also to implement return button on SwiftUI view which will return to UIKit viewController. Do you have any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Please share the code where you open the SwiftUI view.

Comment: You can use the UIHostingController class to achieve that (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller). Assuming that you are using a UINavigationController to push your SwiftUI view embedded within a UIHostingController onto the navigation stack, you don't need to worry about implementing a return button in the SwiftUI view.